# static file load on different route expressjs

Tags: express, handlebars.js

I am learning expressjs and I faced a problem that I found any solution to it. Basically When I am running my express app I can load all static file (CSS, JS) on root route. (localhost:3000). Now let's say I have another route (/users) so when my URL is localhost:3000/users/ I am loading a handlebar page within I have `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/app.css'/>`

I am setting up my static files like this `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , '/public')));`

It loads all static files on root or index file. So when I am on /users directory, that page is looking for app.css in `http://localhost:3000/gifts/css/app.css`

**So how do I get all the static files from any routes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work by changing the path to

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/app.css'/>
```

Comment: thanks mate. problem solved. I understood what I did wrong. Cheers